# ASP.NET AJAX.BeginForm sends request twice and add duplicate entries

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, request, submit

I have an old project to work on (asp .net MVC). When **Using Ajax.BeginForm** with a submit button. It calls the action method **two times**. What could be the reason?

controller source :

```
PatientDataProvider.AddPatient(patient);
return Json(new { redirection = "goToIndex" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

HTML :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjouterPatient", "Patient", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess" }))
```

This is the button :

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit">
   <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check"></i>
       Save
</button>
```

the **OnSuccess** method :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnSuccess(data)
        {
            window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";
        };

//other methods
        jQuery(function ($) {...}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why in the world are you using ajax when you want to redirect?

Comment: @Stephen  : out of the redirect I have other test to do

Comment: What? (the code you have shown is just `location.href = ...`)

Comment: the code I postulated just contains the redirection but I have to test.
I'm doing this just to simplify things